# Get date and timezone from a form

Tags: php, date, symfony, timezone

I get an array from a form $formData:

```
Array ( [first_name] => 12 [last_name] => 1 [date] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2008-01-01 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin ) [sex_id] => 1 [terms] => 1 )
```

How do I get to [date] and  [timezone]?

This doesn't work:

```
$formData['date']->getTimezone();
```

Comment: Did you try `$formData['date']->timezone;`?

Comment: What errors are you getting? `getTimezone` is a method, but it returns an object, not a string [RTFM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), it returns a `DateTimeZone` instance, so you're probably looking for `->getTimezone()->getName();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `$formData['date']` really returns an object of type `DateTime` [getTimezone()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimezone.php) will work. This will return the `DateTimeZone` object.

In order to get the timezone's name use:

```
$formData['date']->getTimezone()->getName()
```

... or ...

```
timezone_name_get($formData['date']->getTimezone());
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah... being a bit slow really, but comment and answer are both correct.

DateTime::getTimezone() returns a DateTimeZone object, see [doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimezone.php)

```
public DateTimeZone DateTime::getTimezone ( void )
```

But you don't necessarily need the object, but if you want to access the field, use

```
$datetime->timezone
```

Or a full example:

```
$array = array(
'blah'  => 0,
'date'  => new Datetime(),
'blub'  => 1
);

var_dump($array);

var_dump($array['date']->timezone);

var_dump($array['date']->getTimezone()->getName());
```

Outputting:

```
array(3) {
  ["blah"]=>
  int(0)
  ["date"]=>
  object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2013-08-29 13:25:08"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
  }
  ["blub"]=>
  int(1)
}
string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
```

Comment: +1 for the doc links, method signature and the _proper_ way of getting to the timezone (through method calls)

Comment: @nifr: I see no 2 sentences that are exactly alike, so copy-pasting isn't on the table here

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to access directly to timezone property? I think it's public

```
class DateTime#1 (3) {
  public $date =>
  string(19) "2013-08-29 13:24:59"
  public $timezone_type =>
  int(3)
  public $timezone =>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}


<?php
$timezone = $frmData['date']->timezone; 
?>
```

Comment: The _proper_ way is as Filou shows: using the methods. It's the safest way. Accessing the property directly isn't as tidy as it could be. Suppose the next major release makes all properties private?

Comment: You are right, it would be a big change that probably would broke a lot of scripts, but it's a posibility we have to take in mind